# JFrog private registry fails to npm install

Tags: npm, artifactory

I'm having issues with JFrog NPM private repositories.

In our CI we configure the npm private registry and then do `npm install` like this:

```
- npm_private_registry https://DOMAIN.jfrog.io/DOMAIN/api/npm/npm-virtual/ $TOKEN
- npm install
```

This code works perfectly fine when we use the `node:12.13.1` Docker image.

Our problem is that as soon as we change the image to a newer one, let's say `node:12.16.1` then the `npm install` command fails.

We then get the following errors:

```
$ npm install
(wd=/builds/DOMAIN/APP)
 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/builds/DOMAIN/APP/node_modules/.staging/react-icons-921e2ffa/go/package.json'
 npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/builds/DOMAIN/APP/node_modules/.staging/intl-58a6f707/locale-data/jsonp/gsw-FR.js'
...
...
...
 npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://DOMAIN.jfrog.io/DOMAIN/api/npm/npm-virtual/next (over 30000ms)
```

We tried various approaches already, but haven't been able to figure anything out just yet.
Does anyone have an idea where to start?
The issue seems quite generic. How is it possible to get timeouts on one version of the `node` image and no issues on another?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this link https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1151 offers some explanation. The timeout got hardcoded down to 30000 ms in npm 16.4.0 via npm-registry-fetch. This has now been reverted to not timeout again https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-fetch/commit/fc5d94c39ca218d78df77249ab3a6bf1d9ed9db1. This fix is in 6.14.5 of npm https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.14.5.

In terms of default npm with node versions this means, releases 12.16.2 and 12.16.3 of node contain this problem via npm 6.14.4.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution was very helpful and allowed us to resolve this problem.